# Неправильная работа рекурсивного перебора

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n, ans = 0, k;
bool row[9], col[9];
bool d1[20], d2[20];
int h[100][100];
void rec(int q, int x, int y) {
    row[x] = col[y] = true;
    d1[x-y+9] = d2[y+x] = true;
    if(!h[x+3 + 10][y+1 + 10])
        h[x+3 + 10][y+1 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x+3 + 10][y-1 + 10])
        h[x+3 + 10][y-1 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x-3 + 10][y-1 + 10])
        h[x-3 + 10][y-1 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x-3 + 10][y+1 + 10])
        h[x-3 + 10][y+1 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x-1 + 10][y+3 + 10])
        h[x-1 + 10][y+3 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x-1 + 10][y-3 + 10])
        h[x-1 + 10][y-3 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x+1 + 10][y-3 + 10])
        h[x+1 + 10][y-3 + 10] = q;
    if(!h[x+1 + 10][y+3 + 10])
        h[x+1 + 10][y+3 + 10] = q;
    if(q + 1 <= k) {
        for(int i = x+1; i <= n; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if(!row[i] && !col[j] && !d1[i-j+9] && !d2[i+j] && !h[i+3 + 10][j+1 + 10] && !h[i+1 + 10][j+3 + 10] && !h[i+3 + 10][j-1 + 10] && !h[i+1 + 10][j-3 + 10] && !h[i-1 + 10][j-3 + 10] && !h[i-1 + 10][j+3 + 10] && !h[i-3 + 10][j+1 + 10] && !h[i-3 + 10][j-1 + 10])
                    rec(q+1, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        ans += 1;
    row[x] = false;
    col[y] = false;
    d1[x-y+9] = d2[y+x] = false;
    if(h[x+3 + 10][y+1 + 10] == q)
        h[x+3 + 10][y+1 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x+3 + 10][y-1 + 10] == q)
        h[x+3 + 10][y-1 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x-3 + 10][y-1 + 10] == q)
        h[x-3 + 10][y-1 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x-3 + 10][y+1 + 10] == q)
        h[x-3 + 10][y+1 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x-1 + 10][y+3 + 10] == q)
        h[x-1 + 10][y+3 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x-1 + 10][y-3 + 10] == q)
        h[x-1 + 10][y-3 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x+1 + 10][y-3 + 10] == q)
        h[x+1 + 10][y-3 + 10] = 0;
    if(h[x+1 + 10][y+3 + 10] == q)
        h[x+1 + 10][y+3 + 10] = 0;
}
int main(){   
    cin >> n >> k;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
            rec(1,i,j);
    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Формулировка задачи такая: найти количества вариантов расстановки k магарадж в доске n*n так, чтобы ни одна магараджа не была битой любой другой. Магараджа может ходить как ферзь и как конь. Программа выдает число, но оно неправильное.
Например: n = 3 и k = 1 выдает правильно (9), а дальше уже неправильно, к примеру 4 и 2 должно быть 20, а выдает 44.
Массивы d1 и d2 - диагонали, row - ряд, col - столб, h - вариации ходами как конь. Если значение ненулевое (или не false), то оно битое магараджей в этот момент.
Помогите найти ошибку

Comment: А как вы гарантируете, что доступ по индексу не выходит за границы диапазонов?

Comment: Для рядов берем чуть больше, но там очевидно, что не выйдет.
Для диагоналей берем так, что у одной диагонали общая сумма х и у, а у второй разность, но так как разность может быть отрицательной - мы добавляем +9 к индексу и берем чуть больше границы массива (на всякий).
Так как конь ходить также может по отрицательному - прибавляем 10.